# How offensive is the expression "I am sick of you"?

Tags: meaning, phrases, expressions, meaning-in-context, offensive-language

**Question 1:** What is the meaning of "I am sick of you" exactly?

**Question 2:** Does the meaning of this expression change depending on the context?

**Question 3:** How offensive is this expression in comparison with some alternatives having similar meanings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means that the other person’s personality or behaviour is so objectionable that the speaker no longer wishes to continue the relationship. It is hard to imagine any context in which it would be well received, unless it was clearly being spoken in jest. It is very offensive compared with most other things that might be said in similar circumstances.

Comment: Can you give me some examples of the same category, please?

Comment: 'I hate you', 'I've just about had enough of you', 'I've had it up to here with you', 'You revolt me'.